# How to be able to reuse column names after deleting them?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, column

So I have a calendar and I made a column, but I didn't give it the right type, so I deleted it and went to make it again, but it won't allow me to create the column again with the same name. So I basically ended up using "ColumnName" instead of "Column Name" everywhere I did this. This strikes me as unprofessional though and I was wondering how I could be able to use the names again?

EDIT: They let you use the name again if you close SP Designer and restart it. Still weird though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deleting you can refresh using the refresh Icon on top of the SharePoint Designer. This will reload the cached information (which includes site column names etc.)

You can also use F5 key to invoke a refresh

Comment: Both good answers, but this was considered more correct as it was more related to the question (because it told me how to do it from SP Designer). Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Try the SharePoint UI from browser instead of SharePoint Designer to delete and re-create a column if you have made any mistake while creating it. You can go to List Settings, go to the Columns section, click the existing column to open its properties. There you will see an option to delete the column. Once deleted, you should be able to re-create it with the same name without any issues. It's advisable to clear the browser cache once (Ctrl+R) after you delete the column.

Comment: This is the correct way.